# Unified Service Desk app not loading updated custom assembly

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2016, unified-service-desk

We are using USD 2.2 with CRM 2016 SP1 on-premise. We have a custom assembly which we deploy to USD using it's Customization File feature.

We have a situation in our staging environment (with multiple CRM backend, front-end servers and USD application being served to users from Citrix servers) whereby if a user logs in for the second time, USD is not able to load our custom assembly from the user's appdata profile ([user name]\appdata\local\microsoft\usd) and comes up with a FileNotFound exception. When the user logs in for the first time or after the user cache has been cleared, USD app works fine, but not on subsequent logins.

I believe the issue has nothing to do with USD because I tried deleting/disabling caching on the browser, the USD app (USD->User Settings) and USD user account (USD->Options) to no avail. Also, the problem does not occur in our dev or QA environments which have a single server configuration.

I am wondering if others have had this or similar issue with USD using user profile management with Citrix or other similar software.

Comment: Did you try to keep the custom assembly in USD installed folder? "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics CRM USD\USD". Try this, may be that will help to solve your issue.

Comment: Hello Renjith. My original question was not accurate as I did not explain the problem very well. So I updated it. To answer your question, it is not feasible for me to add the assembly to those servers as a) i don't have access to them, and b) there are several servers.

Comment: What I mentioned is not in the servers. In your machine where USD client is installed. That should be feasible as it is in your local machine. This is just to rule out that the problem is not with the dlls (obviously it shouldn't be as it is working in your dev environment).